# Generating a .key/.pem etc. file from an Ethereum public key

Tags: openssl, key, ethereum, pem

I am attempting to use `openssl` in order to encrypt a message using the public key of an Ethereum wallet.

Using `openssl rsautl -inkey <publickey> -in <message> -out <message.enc>` as a crude demonstration, I am struggling to understand how I can encode the public key I have as an appropriate file to go under `publickey`. I have searched for an answer, but all `.pem` and `.key` files are generated with new key pairs.

Any indication as to how I could approach this will be appreciated. Please don't hesitate to ask if you would like me to clarify anything!